# MS Access convert short time in form to decimal time in table

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database with a form that contains a "ProcessTime" field, with the format hh:nn and the input mask 00:00. I've got that part working fine. In the Control Source on the associated table, however, I would like the ProcessTime field/column to appear as decimal minutes. I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

For example, a user might enter a ProcessTime in the form as 01:30, meaning 1 hour and 30 minutes. I would like the associated value in the table to then appear as 1.5, meaning 1 and a half hours.

How can I go about modifying the ProcessTime field in the table to show the time in decimal hours? I had assumed there would be some simple "decimal time" format I could enter for the ProcessTime field in Design View, but I haven't found one yet.

I'm using MS Access 2013.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a Calculated Field whose formula is `CDbl([ProcessTime])*24`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no intrinsic format or conversion function for this. Don't modify the field. Do a calculation in query or textbox.

[ProcessTime] is a date/time type? The following expression will work for date/time or text type.
`Hour([ProcessTime]) + Minute([ProcessTime])/60`

Comment: Thanks. The "There is no intrinsic format or conversion function for this" is what I was worried about. I was hoping to avoid creating a new query or calculated field for simplicity and cleanliness, but since it's what all the answers and comments have suggested, I guess I'll proceed down that route.

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox is bound to the field, it will be problematic to make a conversion like that as you will have different data types (date/time and decimal).  If it is not a bound textbox you can split the textbox value on the colon (:) and then concatenate hours & (minutes/60) and then write the information to the table.

```
Dim temp as string

temp = split(ProcessTime.Value,":")

currentDB.Execute "Update <table name> SET ProcessTime=" & temp(0) & temp(1)/60 & "WHERE <condition>;"

'Or you are adding a new record you can do an Insert Query
' Replace the Update statement above with "INSERT INTO <table name> (<other fields>,ProcessTime) VALUES (<other values>," & temp(0) & temp(1)/60 & ");"
```